# Operator overload with a reference return in C++ class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What's the difference between this two function?

```
double &operator[](size_t i) { return features_[i]; }
double operator[](size_t i) const { return features_[i]; }
```

1, the first one allows to modify the `features_[i]` but the second not?

2, which operator will be chosen when I write `Mytype[i] = 0` and `double x = Mytype[i]`?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Depends on whether `Mytype` instance is `const`. In both cases.

Comment: If I declare `Mytpe` as `const`?

Comment: My comment should've hinted at the answer, but since the 2nd overload is marked as `const`, it will be chosen for `const` instances, while the non-`const` method (1st overload) will be chosen for non-`const` instances.

Comment: If I only offer the first function, is there some risks for the `const Mytype` which tries to modify the return value? or the `const` before `Mytype` will guarantee that `Mytype` will not assign the `features_`?

Comment: If you offer only the first overload, then it wouldn't get called if you tried to call it on the `const` object, since the compiler will only look for `const` methods. That's the whole purpose of them - to be called on `const` objects. Why didn't you just: 1) try-out such questions, yourself, and observe what errors the compiler gives you? 2) consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: This code is from a blog which teach the curiously recurring template pattern, and it's not complete project. Thanks for the link. I'll build a minimum project to test it.  ^-^

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. Please note that the second one (const) returns a copy (return by value), which may be ok to modify, but will not modify the original in `Mytype`.

2) It depends solely on the constness of `Mytype`. However, `double x = Mytype[i]` will result in a copy in either case.